# yfinance history function not working with loop

Tags: python, yfinance

I have been getting a new 'issue' with yfinance not downloading the proper data range set when used in a loop to get a range of tickers. This seems to be a recent problem and I am not sure if it is something Yahoo have introduced to limit what data can be accessed, or whether I am doing something wrong.

The code I have been using is:

```
def yfinance_download(TICKER, TIME_PERIOD):
        company = yf.Ticker(f'{TICKER}'.upper())
        hist = company.history(period=TIME_PERIOD).Close
        
        return hist

yfinance_download('PSC.AX', '1y')
```

When I run the above code, it returns the full years worth of data for that single ticker. However when I use a loop to get the data for a list of tickers, it only gives me about 55 days worth of data when until recently it returned the full year.

```
tl = [
    'GT1.AX',
    'GL1.AX',
    'AVZ.AX',
    'CRR.AX',
    'PSC.AX',
]

stock_df_1y = pd.DataFrame()

for t in tl:
    try:
        
        hist_download = yfinance_download(t, '1y')
        stock_df_1y[t] = hist_download
            
    except: pass
        
    print(t)

stock_df_1y
```

Can someone explain what is happening?

Comment: Yahoo finance definitely has rate limiting. I strongly suggest that you do **not** *pass* the exception otherwise if/when there are problems you won't know about it

Comment: The current limit only seems to have started in the last few weeks though which is what is throwing me off. I'm also downloading thousands of tickers at a time, which is why I'm using pass. If an individual ticker doesn't want to cooperate, I don't want to know about it.